# How to hide grandchildren in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I use tree/table model (inherited from QStandardItemModel) and a couple of views for different purposes.

Some rows of the model have children-rows, and some of them may also have children and so on.

In QTreeView I would like to show only top-level rows and theirs "first-level children" - grandchildren and their children should be hidden.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use QSortFilterProxyModel.

Look example

```
bool YourQSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow ( int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent ) const
{
    if (source_parent == qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(sourceModel())->invisibleRootItem()->index())
    {
        // always accept children of rootitem, since we want to filter their children 
        return true;
    }

    return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My working solution, based on Vladislav Mikitich reply:

```
 bool ArchiveQSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    if (source_parent == qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(sourceModel())->invisibleRootItem()->index())
    {
        // always accept children of rootitem, since we want to filter their children
        return true;
    }

    if (source_parent.parent() == qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(sourceModel())->invisibleRootItem()->index())
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (source_parent.parent().parent() == qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(sourceModel())->invisibleRootItem()->index())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);

}
```